# Getting exception Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.<init>

Tags: docker, spring-boot, tomcat, containers

I am getting below exception when I start my spring boot war file in a docker container. Strange thing is, **same war file works absolutely fine when I deploy it in my windows tomcat as well as a linux tomcat**. It is only failing when I launch it in docker container. Below are details.

Exception stack

```
    08-Oct-2018 14:28:48.559 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MySpringBootApp]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/type/AnnotationMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;)V
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport$1.<init>(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:67)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getConfigurationSource(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:66)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:58)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:352)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5204)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more

08-Oct-2018 14:28:48.566 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/app/apache-tomcat-8.5.29/webapps/MySpringBootApp.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MySpringBootApp]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[Loaded java.text.FieldPosition$Delegate from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar]
08-Oct-2018 14:28:48.567 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/app/apache-tomcat-8.5.29/webapps/MySpringBootApp.war] has finished in [32,467] ms
08-Oct-2018 14:28:48.569 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/app/apache-tomcat-8.5.29/webapps/ROOT]
```

Below is docker image I have used with various other parent images.

```
### OpenJDK image
#FROM openjdk:8u181-jdk
#FROM java:8-jre-alpine
#FROM lwieske/java-8:jdk-8u181-slim
FROM lwieske/java-8:jdk-8u152-slim

### Set up app directory structure
WORKDIR /app/rgx/

### Copy class file
COPY . /app/

### Application listening on this port
EXPOSE 9186

### Define environment variable
ENV NAME MyApp

ENV CATALINA_HOME /app/apache-tomcat-8.5.29
ENV PATH $CATALINA_HOME/bin:$PATH

ENV JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre

### Run app
CMD [ "catalina.sh", "run" ]
```

Also, dependencies in pom.xml file as below (Not an entire file).

```
    <properties>
        <springboot.version>1.4.6.RELEASE</springboot.version>
        <swagger.version>2.4.0</swagger.version>
        <tomcat.version>8.0.3</tomcat.version>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <sonar.junit.reportsPath>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <spring.data.commons.version>1.12.1.RELEASE</spring.data.commons.version>
        <spring.data.commons.core.version>1.4.1.RELEASE</spring.data.commons.core.version>
        <spring.data.jpa.version>1.10.2.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
        <spring.boot.starter.test.version>1.4.0.RELEASE</spring.boot.starter.test.version>
        <google.gson.version>2.6.2</google.gson.version>
        <apache.commons.io.version>1.3.2</apache.commons.io.version>
        <google.guava.version>19.0</google.guava.version>
        <harmcrest.version>1.3</harmcrest.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.7.4.201502262128</jacoco.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <spring.test.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.test.version>
        <apache.commons.lang3.version>3.0</apache.commons.lang3.version>
        <ojdbc6.version>11.2.0.2</ojdbc6.version>
        <xalan.version>2.7.1</xalan.version>
        <xercesImpl.version>2.9.1</xercesImpl.version>
        <fop-patch-46319.version>0.93</fop-patch-46319.version>
        <itextpdf.version>7.0.5</itextpdf.version>
        <bcprov-jdk15.version>1.44</bcprov-jdk15.version>
        <bctsp-jdk15.version>1.44</bctsp-jdk15.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.4</commons-lang.version>
        <bcmail-jdk15.version>1.44</bcmail-jdk15.version>
        <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.7</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

..
..
..

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.commons.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.starter.test.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${google.gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.commons.io.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${google.guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>${harmcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.test.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.commons.lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>${ojdbc6.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>${xalan.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>${xercesImpl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>fop-patch-46319</artifactId>
            <version>${fop-patch-46319.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext7-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
            <version>${itextpdf.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
            <version>${bcprov-jdk15.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15</artifactId>
            <version>${bcmail-jdk15.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bctsp-jdk15</artifactId>
            <version>${bctsp-jdk15.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.193</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

I have tried to upgrade spring boot version from **1.3.5.RELEASE** to higher version. But that makes me run into either build errors or **ClassNotFound exception** which I see on my windows laptop as well. Hence I am ruling out those as an option.

Kindly help.

Comment: Why are you not using an [official OpenJDK](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/) docker image? Also the version of Spring Boot 1.3.5.RELEASE is old and not supported any more.

Comment: When I use 1.5.8 version, I get below exception - Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader can not access a member of class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition with modifiers ""

Comment: Irrespective of version of spring boot framework, my question is, why does it work on windows/linux tomcat instance and throw this exception only when I run app in docker container.

Comment: I suspect you have multiple versions of `AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource` on the classpath. That makes the ordering of the classpath important. When the compatible version is first on the classpath it works. When an incompatible version is first it fails. You can see where classes are loaded from by launching the JVM with `-verbose:class`. Also, the likelihood of having an incompatible version is increased because you have declared lots of versions manually rather than using Spring Boot’s dependency management. I’d remove as many of those versions as possible.

Comment: What I with all the versions? Why all the overrides? You are overriding so many versions that you certainly have versions mixed that don't go well together (You are mixing Spring 4.2 and 4.1, using different Spring Data versions etc). Let Spring Boot manage those for you don't do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For starters your dependencies are a mess. You hav so many overrides for the versions that a mix of versions of the same framework is inevitable. You are working around/against the framework instead of using it.

Judging from the way your dependencies are structured you aren't using the `spring-boot-starter-parent` as the `<parent>` of your `pom.xml`. So instead you should have a `<dependencyManagement>` block and import the `spring-boot-dependencies` dependency (See [using maven without a parent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent)).

So add the following to your `pom.xml`(assuming that the `spring.boot.version` is the actual Spring Boot version you want to use, 1.4.6.RELEASE).

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then cleanup your dependencies by removing all the `version` elements and removing the `spring-boot-starter-parent` as dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>${apache.commons.io.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>${google.guava.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>${commons.lang.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>${ojdbc6.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
    <version>${xalan.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>${xercesImpl.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>fop-patch-46319</artifactId>
    <version>${fop-patch-46319.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext7-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
    <version>${itextpdf.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
    <version>${bcprov-jdk15.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15</artifactId>
    <version>${bcmail-jdk15.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bctsp-jdk15</artifactId>
    <version>${bctsp-jdk15.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Remove the `org.springframework.data` dependencies, as those are included in the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. The same applies to the `hamcrest-all` and `Junit` dependencies those are included in the `spring-boot-starter-test` dependencies. Spring Boot will also manage the version of `lombok,`HikariCP` and others.

Remove the unneeded properties from the `<properties>` section to clean up things. If you want to upgrade to a newer Spring Boot version the only thing you need to do is upgrade the version in the `dependencyManagement` section to get new versions of all related frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have a thing or two about the spring parent & dependency management from this thread. However, I can't accept it as an answer because it did not work for me. As a work around, I have removed Spring Data dependencies and now application is working fine in containers. I am caching data needed in application from static files that I copy in docker image rather than database as done in previous approach.